# Find and Replace but format nested value based on number of characters?

Tags: notepad++

Evening all! Bit of a tough one which I don't know whether can be done?!

I have a file with thousands of lines. I want to search for this:

```
TheValue="12345678"
```

Then format the number inside the "" marks based on how many characters there are. So for example:

---

If there's 1 character inside "", change it from:

```
TheValue="1"
```

To:

```
TheValue="1x"
```

---

---

If there's 2 characters inside "", change it from:

```
TheValue="12"
```

To:

```
TheValue="12x"
```

---

---

If there's 3 characters inside "", change it from:

```
TheValue="123"
```

To:

```
TheValue="1y23x"
```

---

If there's 4 characters inside "", change it from:

```
TheValue="1234"
```

To:

```
TheValue="12y34x"
```

---

---

If there's 5 characters inside "", change it from:

```
TheValue="12345"
```

To:

```
TheValue="1z23y45x"
```

---

But then anything over 5 just shifts the additional numbers to the left of **z**

If there's 6/7/8 characters inside "", change it from:

```
TheValue="123456"
TheValue="1234567"
TheValue="12345678"
```

To:

```
TheValue="12z34y56x"
TheValue="123z45y67x"
TheValue="1234z56y78x"
```

---

Comment: You'll need multiple (I count 3) searches for that, with [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: I tried using TheValue="[^A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]" replaced by TheValue="[^A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]x" but it just prints the search value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I came up with a solution! It's quite manual, but I'm cool with that ~

Find:

```
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
TheValue="([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})"
```

Replace with:

```
TheValue="$1x"
TheValue="$1x"
TheValue="$1y$2x"
TheValue="$1y$2x"
TheValue="$1z$2y$3x"
TheValue="$1z$2y$3x"
TheValue="$1z$2y$3x"
TheValue="$1z$2y$3x"
TheValue="$1z$2y$3x"
TheValue="$1z$2y$3x"
```

Obviously you do them once by one. Once I get all to using 5 digits (x, y AND z) I can just increment the first ([a-zA-Z0-9]{6}) value.

Comment: You can combine the first 2 cases by using `{1,2}` instead of `{1}` and `{2}`. Similarly you can combine the 3rd and 4th cases and the rest of the cases, ending up with 3 searches.